# how to filter a table that having exactly the specified values in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I need to filter a table with exact values.
I have googled almost a day now, I wonder if you guys can help me

I have a table like this:

```
    ID  |  group ID  | tax Id
    -------------------------
    1   |  1         | 1
    2   |  2         | 1
    3   |  2         | 2
    4   |  3         | 2
    5   |  3         | 3
    6   |  3         | 4
    7   |  4         | 1
    8   |  4         | 4
    9   |  5         | 2
   10   |  5         | 4
   11   |  6         | 3
   12   |  6         | 4
```

I need to get the group Id only when the tax ids are exactly 2,3, and 4, which is group id 3.
If I put WHERE TAX_ID IN (2,3,4) I will get these tax groups back 3,5,6.
What I want is just tax group 3 only.
I hope this is not a duplicate question, since I could not find when I Google it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do... `WHERE "tax Id" IN (2,3,4)`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the time to answer my question. Joachim, if I put  IN (2,3,4) the following tax groups with tax id 2,3, and 4 will be selected. For example if I have group id 5 with tax id 2 and 4, it will be selected instead of only group id 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `group by` clause on group_id column and `having` clause to count distinct tax_id to be equal to 3 where tax id is 2 or 3 or 4

Not exists will take care of the condition where the group should contain only the given set if elements and not any additional elements

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01459/3)**

```
SELECT [group_ID]
FROM Table1 T
WHERE [tax_Id] in (2,3,4)
And not exists
( select 1 from Table1 E
Where T.group_id = E.group_id
And tax_id not in (2,3,4)
)
Group by group_id
Having count(distinct tax_id) =3
```

Comment: Hi Radar, I thank you for your time to answer my question. I have tried this too btw, what happened is that when I changed the query just to get only one tax id 1, the correct answer will be group id 1, but this will return 1,2,and 4 for the tax group

Comment: Here is the updated SQL querty btw: SELECT [group_ID]
  FROM Table1
  WHERE [tax_Id] in (1)
  GROUP BY [group_ID]
  having count(distinct [tax_Id]) =1

Comment: @johnsmith, added not exists to make sure the set contains only those elements, try now

Comment: you are the best! I really appreciate your help. My vote is  for you.